# Motion disable AVI Videos

Tags: raspberry-pi, motion

My motion (running on raspberry) is storing `.avi` files.
`output_pictures off` is set, so i don't know why motion does this.

Anyone a idea how I can disable this?

Comment: Try setting `ffmpeg_output_movies` to `off`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generation of moving image files is controlled by the config setting `ffmpeg_output_movies`. Setting this to `off` should resolve the problem.